# table with monospaced and nonbreaking spaces

Tags: tables, typewriter

I have a xtable generated in R/Sweave that I would like displayed in portrait mode in a pdf. The spaces in the spacedSeq should properly align the sequences.

How can I force this to be in a monospace font.
I can use XeteX if necessary but I don't know what fonts are available to me from my TeXlive installation on OS X.

a subset of the table below:

```latex
% latex table generated in R 2.13.0 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Tue Nov  1 13:53:39 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlllrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & rname & spacedSeq & edits & RB494N & RB494T & RB495N & RB495T & RB498N & RB498T \\ 
  \hline
1 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAA & 6:T 25:G &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  2 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT & 6:T &   7 &   5 &  21 &   4 &   5 &   2 \\ 
  3 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT & 6:T &  14 &  16 & 113 &  20 &  30 &   4 \\ 
  4 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTA & 6:T 28:T &   2 &   1 &   8 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  5 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTG & 6:T 28:T &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  6 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTGT & 6:T 28:T &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  7 & hsa-let-7a-1 &      AGATGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT & 6:T 9:G &   1 &   0 &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  8 & hsa-let-7a-1 &        AGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT &  &   5 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   8 &   1 \\ 
  9 & hsa-let-7a-1 &        AGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTT &  &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  10 & hsa-let-7a-1 &        AGGTAGTGGGTTGTATAGT & 15:A &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Not sure if I understand you correct. The normal way to make unbreakable spaces (in any font) is to use `~`.

Answer (score 2):

This requires the **array** package:

```
\usepackage{array}
```

Then you can use the `>{...}` syntax for adding declarations for one column; spaces not to be ignored are obtained by `~`

```
\begin{tabular}{rl>{\ttfamily}llrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & rname & \normalfont spacedSeq & edits & RB494N & RB494T & RB495N & RB495T & RB498N & RB498T \\
  \hline
 1 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAA & 6:T 25:G &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
 2 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT & 6:T &   7 &   5 &  21 &   4 &   5 &   2 \\
 3 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT & 6:T &  14 &  16 & 113 &  20 &  30 &   4 \\
 4 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTA & 6:T 28:T &   2 &   1 &   8 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
 5 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTG & 6:T 28:T &   1 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 \\
 6 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTGT & 6:T 28:T &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
 7 & hsa-let-7a-1 & AGATGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT & 6:T 9:G &   1 &   0 &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
 8 & hsa-let-7a-1 & ~~AGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGT &  &   5 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   8 &   1 \\
 9 & hsa-let-7a-1 & ~~AGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTTT &  &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
10 & hsa-let-7a-1 & ~~AGGTAGTGGGTTGTATAGT & 15:A &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

One has to override the `\ttfamily` declaration in the header, which can be done by

```
\normalfont spacedSeq
```

or

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{spacedSeq}
```

Comment: You may want to have the heading `spacedSeq` non-monospaced. The additional column declaration can be overridden using `\multicolumn{1}{l}{spacedSeq}`.