# How to vertically align 'numbers' in a table? [pairs of numbers given as strings]

Tags: tables, siunitx

I display two sorts of values (say, A and B) in one table. The values are
generated in R and I automatically create strings like "A (B)", so all values of
type B are put in parentheses and are appended to the values of A. As you can
see from the resulting table, the spacing is not quite right, it depends on the
number of digits of B:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \toprule
   27.8 ( 2.8) &  38.4 ( 3.1)\\
  126.8 (10.3) & 171.9 (11.2)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I am wondering what good ways are to fix this?

One option would be to check the number of digits of B and add `\phantom{0}`
accordingly, or `\ \,` also does it. But I would be interested in whether it is
possible to align the numbers without these 'hacks'. Ideally, I would like to keep
the numbers as they are (for example, to be able to easily use the same table in
non-LaTeX documents).

In theory, a solution could be to align the numbers according to two dots (like
an `alignat` environment in comparison to `align`) . But I'm not sure whether
this can be done (with `siunitx` (?))

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/table-with-monospaced-and-nonbreaking-spaces) is what I found on this topic, but adding `~` is like the above (thus required adjustments of the table entries) and monospaced fonts ... hmmm... doesn't seem very elegant.

**UPDATE**

Trial after David's post:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{dcolumn}:
\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rD{.}{.}{-1}}
  \toprule
   27.8 &  38.4 (2.3)\\
  126.8 & 171.9 (29.1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
With \texttt{siunitx}:
\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{S
                S}
  \toprule
   27.8 &  38.4(3)\\
  126.8 & 171.9(1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
How it should look like:
\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \toprule
   27.8 &  38.4 (\ \,2.3)\\
  126.8 & 171.9 (29.1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn’t that horizontal alignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `\usepackage{dcolumn}`  then you can replace  `r` by `D{.}{.}{-1}` for columns centred on a `.`  (There are other options, see the package documentation). `siunitx` package `S` column has similar features.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{
D{.}{.}{3.2} 
D{.}{.}{3.1} @{\,}
D{.}{.}{3.2} 
 }
  \toprule
   27.8 &  38.4 &(2.3)\\
  126.8 & 171.9 &(29.1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Or this version which doesn't require the extra `&`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\DDC}c}
\def\DDC#1(#2){\DC@..{3.2}#1\DC@end\,(\DC@..{2.1}#2\DC@end)}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{
D{.}{.}{3.2} 
E
 }
  \toprule
   27.8 &  38.4 (2.3)\\
  126.8 & 171.9 (29.1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With Colour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn,color}

\makeatletter

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\myDDC}c}
\def\myDDC\ignorespaces{\@ifnextchar!{\color{red}\@myDDC\@gobble}{\@myDDC}}
\def\@myDDC#1(#2){\DC@..{3.2}#1\DC@end\,(\DC@..{2.1}#2\DC@end)}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\myDC}c<{\DC@end}}
\def\myDC\ignorespaces{\@ifnextchar!{\color{red}\@myDC\@gobble}{\@myDC}}
\def\@myDC{\DC@..{3.2}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{FE}
  \toprule
   27.8 & !38.4 (2.3)\\
  !126.8 & 171.9 (29.1)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi David, many thanks. It sounds good, but I'm not sure if I use it correctly. Please see the update of my post. I read in the `siunitx` manual ("uncertainty"), but it seems strange: Once the content of `()` contains another dot, `S` seems to get confused: `siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-uncertainty"` Also, `dcolumn` seems to align the uncertainties to the left, not to the (second) dots. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MariusHofert Not sure I understand do you want to separately align on the `.` in both numbers (if so it would be easiest to add a `&`)

Comment: Hi David. Indeed, yes. The last version in the above update shows this (but I had to manually insert `\ \,`). I agree that it would normally be easiest to use double the amount of columns, but this is not really possible with the program that generates the table (all done automatically...).

Comment: @MariusHofert ah I just posted a version with extra `&` :-)

Comment: @MariusHofert see update version not requiring the extra `&` posted

Comment: Very good, thanks David. You should put this (with variable widths) in `dcolumn` as another column type.

Comment: Hmmm... now I know why I was originally looking for a solution based on `siunitx`, `dcolumn` doesn't easily handle colorizing of table cells, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42765/colored-text-with-dcolumn

Comment: @MariusHofert sure it does, try `\newcolumntype{E}{>{\color{red}\DDC}c}`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the update. This gives colors for full columns, right? In my 'real application', the table is autogenerated and only cells fulfilling certain requirements should be colored. I do this by writing `\color{blue} 4.35 (1.23)` (so essentially pasting the color command before the number). With `siunitx`, this essentially works, but that package changes the numbers in a way which is not clear to me. I just posted this as a different question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114741/how-to-display-numbers-in-the-format-12-3-4-56-in-a-table-column

Comment: @MariusHofert define a colored column type then go `\multicolumn{1}{F}{4.35 (1.23)}` or define `\DDC` to make every entry prefixed with `*` be red or ....

Comment: @MariusHofert colour example added

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a monospace font for your table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\texttt{
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \toprule
   27.8 ( 2.8) &  38.4 ( 3.1)\\
  126.8 (10.3) & 171.9 (11.2)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please expand it to a complete answer?