# How to display numbers in the format 12.3 (4.56) in a table column?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I would like to print numbers in a table in the form `12.3 (4.56)` using
`siunitx`. How can this be achieved?

I'm a bit worried that `siunitx` changes the numbers in various ways
and I would like to understand why. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[separate-uncertainty]
                S[separate-uncertainty, uncertainty-separator={\ }]
                S[uncertainty-separator={\ }]} % table-format=2.1(1.2) doesn't help here
  \toprule
  12.3 (456) & 12.3 +- 4.56 & 12.3 +- 4.56\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

My first trial was actually `12.3 (4.56)` but that gives an error. It seems that
there is no second dot allowed (I was hoping that this is possible with
`table-format`, but it didn't work) unless one uses a syntax like `12.3 +-
4.56`.

Note:

- That both numbers (the 'main' number and the 'uncertainty') are perfectly
  formatted in my case. They shouldn't be changed/adjusted.
- I am not looking for a solution with separate columns for the 'main' number
  and the 'uncertainty'.
- I am specifically looking for a solution with `siunitx` in order to have the numbers nicely aligned (ideally according to both decimal dots) and to be able to colorize certain table entries.

Comment: Hmm, why the second point: _I am not looking for a solution with separate columns for the 'main' number and the 'uncertainty'_ ?

Comment: The table is autogenerated with a different program in a quite sophisticated way, including the corresponding header. Suddenly having roughly double the amount of columns is technically not possible, that's why I was hoping for a solution without a second column. I can hack it in the sense that I can determine the length of the numbers in the parentheses and fill the 'gaps' with spaces or `\phantom` commands. Not very elegant, though. Given that `siunitx` is so sophisticated, I was hoping this could be done with this package. I was quite a bit disappointed it makes so many assumptions...

Comment: If all the number tuples are of the form `a (b)` you could simply _find and replace_ `(` with `& (`. And for the header line you could _find and replace_ `&` with `} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{`, in the end copying `\multicolumn{2}{c}{` to the beginning and `}` just before the `\\ ` . Finally, double the number of `S` columns. Or is there any reason this would not work?

Comment: Of course *I* could do that :-) But this is part of a software and 99% of the users couldn't do that :-) They want to hit a button...

Comment: Ow, that's a low blow, Users! Don't get me started about them ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physicists would complain about `12.3 (4.56)`. `12.3` means that the last certain digit is the `3`, e.g. you don't know what the exact following digits are. Lacking that knowledge, giving an error like `4.56` does not make any sense, as this would be more accurate than your actual result. So errors should have at best as many significant digits as the result. If your error computation gives `4.56` you'd need to round it at lest to `4.6`. Often it is considered even better to have only one significant digit for the error (two is the first digit is a `1`), so your result *should probably* be `12 (5)` be Note that you don't use normal rounding rules, errors are always rounded up to avoid understating the value of the error, while results are rounded normally to the precision of the error. Also, the error is always given as *digits from the end*, I don't think that you usually use a decimal separator there. So you have three options:

- use `12.3 (4.6)` if you don't know a more precise value
- use `12.30 (4.56)` if you know the value to a higher precision than `12.3` lets on
- use `12 (5)` as the very large value of the uncertainty suggests

So I think `12.30(456)` is fine, as well as `12.30 +- 4.56`. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to separate the uncertainties as you requested, although I personally don't think that this would be a good idea. However an *unexpected* behaviour occured: If you have numbers with and without decimal point in the same column, the alignment is off by about the width of the decimal separator.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[uncertainty-separator={\ }]
                S[separate-uncertainty, uncertainty-separator={\ }]
                S[separate-uncertainty]
                S} 
  \toprule
  12.30 (456) & 12.30 +- 4.56 & 12.3 +- 4.56 & 12.30 (456)\\
  12.3 (46) & 12.3 +- 4.6 & 12.3 +- 4.6 & 12.3 (46)\\
  12 (5) & 12 +- 5 & 12 +- 5 & 12 (5)\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I accept this as an answer, but it was not quite what I was hoping for. The second number in my case is just another piece of information, it is not the uncertainty of the first number and therefore the number of digits can be larger than for the first number. I was hoping to use this "uncertainty" construction/approach of siunitx to get the numbers side-by-side. But I see it's not so simple. Nevertheless, your post was very informative, thanks again.